# How can i delete value of an array stored in session in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My products ids are stored in the session in 'pid' in array form. Now, I want to delete one of its value and the value comes from $id variable. How can I delete one of its value?

I tried unsetting it like below, but it's not working.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('pid', $id);
```

Comment: [Read this...](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/242318/)

Comment: Read this.. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//first get whole array in session sored as pid key  
     $ses_array = $this->session->userdata('pid');
//remove value you want to delete means $id
     if(($key = array_search($id, $ses_array)) !== false) { 
           unset($ses_array[$key]);
     }
//again set this array to session
$this->session->set_userdata('pid',$ses_array)
     print_r($this->session->userdata('pid'));
```

Answer (score 0):

CI session `unset_userdata()` method wont support unset value inside multilevel array.

**PS**: you can access `Session` class `userdata` variable, it's default `public`

Try this way

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('pid' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6)));
unset($this->session->userdata['pid'][4]); //your id key ['pid'][$id]
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```